# Broadcasted message will not show up in browser console after being sent, actioncable and redis development env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actioncable

I have got redis setup for windows running the server from redis cli

```
C:\program files\redis>redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Development cable.yml is

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
```

Notifications channel rb

```
class NotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "notifications_#{current_user.id}"
  end
end
```

Start rails server and load up the page, server prints

```
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2018-09-29 13:07:17 +1000
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive, Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vcGVvcGxlcy9Vc2VyLzUwMQ)
NotificationsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
NotificationsChannel is streaming from notifications_501
```

notifications.js on page is

```
App.notifications = App.cable.subscriptions.create("NotificationsChannel", {
  connected:  function() {
    alert("hello")
  },
  recieved: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

Alert pops up saying is connected on page load. In another terminal run rails console

```
irb> ActionCable.server.broadcast("notifications_501", body: "hello")
```

Look back in rails server output

```
NotificationsChannel transmitting {"body"=>"hello"} (via streamed from notifications_501)
```

But the console doesnt show the JSON object?

** **Edit** **

Creat another instance of redis server

```
C:\program files\redis>redi-cli
127.0.0.1:6379>subscribe "notifications_501"
1)"subscribe"
2)"notifications_501"
3)(integer) 1
```

Open another cli

```
127.0.0.1:6379>publish "notifications_502" "{\"body\":\"hello\"}"
```

It transmits to both the rails server and the subscribed redis server

```
NotificationsChannel transmitting {"body"=>"hello"} (via streamed from notifications_501)
```

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I got this working but had to change my notifications.js to coffee. Not sure why yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason it didn't work for you on your first try might be because of a typo when naming `received` function. You did `recieved` instead.

Comment: You most certainly would be right! I tried it then and it works fine. It also helped me with another issue while trying to get other DOM behavior working which I just couldn't with coffeescript in the received function.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change `notifications.js` to `notfications.coffee` and have code like this

```
App.notificationss = App.cable.subscriptions.create "NotificationsChannel",
  connected: ->
  # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
  # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    alert("hello")
  # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
```

Not sure why normal javascript is not working..